# Using object-filter module issue

Tags: node.js

I am trying to run this script that will filter my object o1 with the condition `>0` so the expected output should be `{ a: 1, d: 42 }` but nothing happens. I installed the modules `assert` and `object-filter` using npm. No errors occurs during the execution of the script. What I am doing wrong? I am new to node.js, thank you!

```
var assert = require('assert');
var objfilter = require('object-filter');

var o1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: -1,
  c: 0,
  d: 42
};

objfilter(o1, function (n) {
  return n > 0;
  console.log(n>0);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to log something after a `return` statement, so the function as already ended and the `console.log` is never called.

Try this:

```
var objfilter = require('object-filter');

var o1 = {
  a : 1,
  b : -1,
  c : 0,
  d : 42
};

var filtered = objfilter(o1, function (n) {
  return n > 0;
});

console.log('filtered result: %j', filtered);
```